# WSVR0652W: The size of thread pool "WebContainer" has reached 80 percent of its maximum

Tags: was

WSVR0652W: The size of thread pool "WebContainer" has reached 80 percent of its maximum.

I got the above error.can anyone tell me when we will get the above message?

Answer (score 0):

This is an informational message. The Application Server does emit messages when
the size of the WebContainer thread pool approaches its maximum.